# Picking from a set, then picking from a subset: what are the odds of getting the same element?

Tags: probability

If you pick an element from a set at random, then pick an element from a non-empty subset of that set at random, what are the odds that you'll get the same element both times?  For example, if you pick a random member of Congress (535 elements), then pick a random Senator (100 elements, all of them members of Congress), what are the odds that you get the same person both times?

Am I correct that this is simply $\frac{1}{\text{size of the set}}$, ie. that the odds of getting a Representative rather than a Senator in my first pick doesn't matter?

Comment: You need to account for the probability that the initial selection is in the group: $\frac{100}{535}$

Comment: then multiplied by $1/100$ that the second time you pick that person: so your answer is right, provided that the subset is not empty.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted his result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of members in Congress

Let $n$ be the number of members in the Senate

Then the probability that the member selected from Congress and from Senate are the same is

$$\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{N}$$

which agrees with your result

**Note:**

> the odds of getting a Representative rather than a Senator in my
>   first pick doesn't matter?

That's not true, since given that you initially selected a representative, the probability is $0$

Comment: I agree, but the OP may have meant "the odds ... doesn't matter" in the sense that the final answer is determined only by the size of the entire set (that is, the $N$ in $\frac1N$) and not by the relative size of the subset (which gives us the fraction $\frac nN$).